# XML format and SOAP issue

Tags: php, soap-client

```
<xs:element name="getTestRunIdsResponse">
  <xs:complexType>
     <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" nillable="truetype="ax28:ServiceTestLab"/>  
     </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I have an XML file response from a web services with above characteristics, when I run  the following instruction

```
$values =  $client->getTestRunIds(array("startTime"=>1358515543000, "endTime"=>1359385988000));
```

and i do an `echo($values)` i got the following error

> SoapFault exception: [Client] looks like we got no XML document

Please any help to solve this problem.

Comment: are you closing the first `<xs:element` tag at the end? Or is this your whole xml file?

Comment: no this is not the whole xml file!. Actually i am reading this from a remote web service!

Comment: I suspect there's a timeout on the retrieval of the WSDL